# syntax error, unexpected ')' after Laravel update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have updated my laravel project to `"laravel/framework": "^8.12"` from laravel 5.7, but after updating when I run `composer dump-autoload` it returns this error

```
Generating optimized autoload files> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In TestDatabases.php line 148:

  syntax error, unexpected ')'
```

here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.8",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive": "~1.1",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.14"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php",
            "app/Helpers/agent_helper.php",
            "app/Helpers/user-helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: Please share more details, like the **exact** error message and your attempts to resolve it. I would assume that removing the syntax error could be a good starting point

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: What's on line 148 in file TestDatabases.php?

Comment: php 7.4 @GertB.

Comment: this is not my project file, looks like framework file @Gowire

Comment: how can I remove syntax error this is not my project file @NicoHaase

Comment: @MVP In that case, how do you include TestDatabase.php into your project? I guess that you have some syntax problem near that inclusion. For example missing a semicolon, paranthesis, or similar, that generates a syntax error later when an unexpected ')' appears

Comment: "Looks like framework file" is still too broad - can you share the exact path of that file?

Comment: Are you sure that the CLI php version is not lower than 7.3? (run php -v) it can be a different version and will throw that error.

Comment: cli showing 7.2.34 although I have assigned 7.4 with that domain, as it was not being updated on cli I have updated laravel with a flag called --ignore-platform-reqs@GertB.

Comment: I can not locate that file because the error does not show any path to that file, I also tried to find that with phpstorm find everywhere feature, but it was unable to find it @NicoHaase

Comment: @MVP there is your problem. Laravel 8 requires php 7.3 or higher. --ignore-platform-reqs is a bad idea: the requirements are there for a reason. Set the php version on cli to 7.4 and it will work

Comment: @GertB. I am sorry about that reply, if I navigate to that project and check php -v it shows 7.4 but if I check globally for all domain it shows 7.2. so 7.2 is for global not for that domain

Comment: @MVP Since you needed to run it with --ignore-platform-reqs to make it work, I think you are running it from the global 7.2 version. to be sure you can run the command using the full php 7.4 path: path/to/php composer install

Comment: To fix this particular error, you need to be on at least PHP 8.1 to run. in Symfony Finder, this line needs PHP 8.1: `array_map($this->normalizeDir(...), $glob)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade your PHP installation to at least version 7.3 to resolve the issue.

PHP 7.2 is [EOL](https://www.php.net/eol.php) (end of life) since 30 Nov 2020!

As already stated in the comments:

> Laravel 8 requires php 7.3 or higher

Larvel 8 has the following PHP version constraint in `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
  "php": "^7.3|^8.0"
}
```

Do **NOT** run `composer` with the `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag unless you have a (very rare) valid reason to do so.

Comment: my php version is already 7.4 as I stated in comments, I've cross checked it with `php -v`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating Ubuntu to version 20. I had both php 7.4 and php 7.2 versions on my machine.  I set my dev environ to php 7.2 to run an older Laravel 5.6 web app, but is also working on a Laravel 8 web app.
I got the same error `In TestDatabases.php line 159: syntax error, unexpected ')'` when I tried `php artisan serve` for Laravel 8.
I solved the error by running the following commands in terminal (directory is inconsequential):

```
user1@user1-Ubuntu:/var/www/html/laravel8-website$sudo a2dismod php7.2
user1@user1-Ubuntu:/var/www/html/laravel8-website$sudo a2enmod php7.4
user1@user1-Ubuntu:/var/www/html/laravel8-website$sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
user1@user1-Ubuntu:/var/www/html/laravel8-website$sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

At first I had not run the command `update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4` and only disabled php7.2 and enabled 7.4 then restarted the server.  But still got the above error despite `phpinfo()` method telling me I have `php7.4.20` running.
I checked php version using `php -v` command in  terminal and got `PHP 7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun  4 2021 21:22:16) ( NTS )` output.
The golden nugget in this wordy answer was also running `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4` command in terminal and restarting server.  It works vice versa also.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing with latest php and latest laravel. I got my files from github laravel\laravel. I fixed it but not sure if it's my mistake (proably is) or if it's actually a bug in the code?

in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/Concerns/TestDatabases.php
On line 158 and 163, at the end of the line there is a comma, which is followed by a close bracket ). So I took out the comma at the end of both lines and now there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the Same Issue. After upgrading to 7.3, it solved. Upgrade PHP 7.2 to 7.3/higher, it will be solved.

**Steps for upgrading to 7.3:** 
Check your current PHP version.

```
# php -v
PHP 7.2.36
```

In order to install PHP 7.3, we need to add the repository first:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then run an update:

```
# apt-get update
```

After completing the update, we need to install the PHP 7.3.

```
# apt install php7.3
```

Then install the required PHP packages based on your current installation:

```
# apt install php7.3-common php7.3-cli php7.3-bz2 php7.3-curl php7.3-gd php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-readline php7.3-xml php7.3-zip php7.3-fpm php7.3-bcmath php7.3-mbstring
```

After a successful installation, we can disable the old 7.2 and then enable 7.3:

```
# a2dismod php7.2

# a2enmod php7.3
```

Then restart Apache:

```
# service apache2 restart
```

The new PHP version should be active now. You can verify it from the command line:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.3.28
```